# How can i make a gradient background without changing background size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to create an animated background, but without changing the background size, because I have problems with my website fit if I change the background-size up to 100 percent in body.

My website will lose his fit.

This is solvable in js??
Here is the code:

```css
  body {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 90vh;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

h1,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS3 Animated Gradient Background</h1>
```

Comment: Could you post it as a Snippet for a clearer view of the issue ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760206